# How does this Matplotlib code snippet work

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am relatively new to programming with Pandas and Matplotlib.

I found this code snippet on this forum and used it successfully, but would like to understand it better.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
new_zinv2.plot(ax=ax, x_compat=True)
```

new_zinv2 is the name of my dataframe.

I would like to understand the contents inside the plot method, as this is the code snippet I lifted.  What is the meaning of "ax=ax" and x_compat=True ?

I've tried to read the documentation, but I still don't understand (and I'd like to know how and why it works).

Thanks

Comment: It works because your `pandas.DataFrame` has a `.plot` method (e.g. [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)) and it has an `ax` parameter. `pandas.DataFrame.plot` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to rename the variables for *clarity*, but this changes nothing about the code.

The first lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_fig, my_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
```

Use a function from matplotlib to create two objects, a figure, and a set of subplots. Since this function returns **two** things the assignment of `my_fig, my_ax =` assigns the first thing returned (the figure) to the variable `my_fig` and the second thing returned (the set of suplots) to the variable my_ax.

Then the second line:

```
new_zinv2.plot(ax=my_ax, x_compat=True)
```

uses the DataFrame function to plot. The plot function takes various arguments that you can use to change defaults or how you plot. `ax=my_ax` tells DataFrame.plot where to plot the figure, in this case it will plot the DataFrame on the (20,20) subplot we already created in the first line which we assigned to the variable `my_ax`, not it's own brand new default figure. `x_compat=True` is another argument you can specify and only takes a Boolean value, which in this case just modifies how the x-ticks are displayed for `datetime` values.

Comment: While I didn't DV this answer, others often DV answers to poorly presented questions. Questions such as this are typically DVed, closed, and deleted. As such, you're likely wasting your time. SO is here to [create a repository of **good** questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/7758804), which can be used as a resource by others. **If the quality of a question can be improved by editing, do so,** otherwise it's advised to DV and vote to close. [Meta: Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/7758804)